# Jquery adding days to a date (abnormal results)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, date

This question is very common. and I know, I've tried the solutions I found here the code works but the results are abmormal

I am trying to add days to a date like 15, 30, 60
but the results I get have months changed abnormally for better understanding I have a jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/CjEEs/

INPUT: 9/2/2014

AFTER ADDING 15 DAYS

DESIRED OUTPUT: 24/02/2014

OUTPUT WHICH I GET: 03/08/2016

JavaScript which I am using

```
 var terms = $("#terms").val();
        var date = new Date();
        date.setDate(date.getDate() + terms);
        var day = ("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2);
        var month = ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
        var final = date.getFullYear()+"-"+(month)+"-"+(day);
        $("#duedate").val(final);
```

Thankyou!

Comment: `terms` is a string, you need a number http://jsfiddle.net/CjEEs/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var terms = 15;
var txt = "09/02/2014";
var sp = "/";
var arr = txt.split(sp);
txt = arr[0];
arr[0] = arr[1];
arr[1] = txt;
txt = arr.join(sp);
var dt = new Date(txt);
console.log(dt);//prints: Date {Sun Feb 09 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)}
dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + terms);
console.log(dt);//prints: Date {Mon Feb 24 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)}
```

Comment: u can directly use the Date constructor to parse string date which takes argument in MM/dd/yyyy format